# If playback doesnt begin shortly

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, video

I have just installed a Ubuntu guest on a Windows 10 laptop. I also have guest additions installed and have access to USB's etc. The problem is when i try to play  video on both chromium and Firefox. i get the error "if playback doesn't begin shortly try restarting your device". The display settings are set at 128MB video memory and 2D and 3D disabled, it doesn't work when i enable them either. Is there something else that i need to do? Thanks

Comment: VMs are useful for a lot of things but certainly not for games and multimedia. What's the point in running a VM to play what can be done perfectly in the host OS?

Comment: I think you answered your own question here "The display settings are set at 128MB video memory and 2D and 3D disabled", in this day of HD video 128mb is nothing and you NEED some kind of (at least 2d, preferably 3d) video acceleration.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for the reply. I had the same issues when i had 3D enabled. I think it could be an issue with html5 player which im looking into at the min.

Comment: Try to use 256mb of vram too. HTML 5 is a bit more demanding than flash.

Answer (score -1):

I regularly have the same problem. For me, this works: Click on the Pause (||) button in the lower left corner, then click on the Play arrow which has replaced it. The video then proceeds to play normally.

Comment: It's inside a Virtual Machine. Probably nothing to do with it and, as I commented above, what OP is trying to do is nonsensical, to say the least.

Comment: @CelticWarrior My situation is not in a VM, and I still experience the problem described. I don't understand why my answer is down-voted because you think OP is doing something stupid.

Comment: Down-voted precisely because it answers nothing. The OP complains about what happens inside a VM. Whatever happens to you in a regular system is irrelevant and not applicable.

Comment: @CelticWarrior so trying to watch a youtube video in vbox is nonsensical??if you dont know how to fix the problem dont bother replying..i would like to fix this issue in case it leads to other issues down the line when i have installed more apps that i need to run in ubuntu

Comment: @user3046660 It definitely IS nonsensical. The purpose of a VM is to run software that can't run in the host system, for testing purposes or whatever.  The virtualized hardware is limited and any graphically demanding task should be expected to run poorly, be it games or even video. The Windows 10 host should run that and more perfectly. FYI, I didn't answer precisely because of that, just commented. Please keep your abusive comments to yourself. Thanks.

Comment: i wasnt sure if guest additions had installed correctly, if something went wrong during the update or upgrade.it could be an underlying issue that will affect future work i need to do inside vbox. Videos on youtube should be playing in vbox, especially with the resources i have assigned to it. Your replies deserved my response, which wasnt exactly abusive now was it.